# DeleteByQuery on spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In Elastic REST API the operations _update_by_query and _delete_by_query are very similar:
They both accept a query, they have similar properties and similar behavior.

However, the implementation in spring-data-elasticsearch is nothing like that:

_update_by_query on spring-data-elasticsearch is model by
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.UpdateQuery

e.g. something like this:

```
final BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
  .filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(STATUS_SEARCH_FIELD).lt(EsMessage.STATUS))
final NativeSearchQuery nsq = new NativeSearchQuery(boolQuery);
final UpdateQuery updateQuery = UpdateQuery.builder(nsq)
  .withScriptType(ScriptType.INLINE)
  .withScript(UPDATE_SCRIPT)
  .withParams(UPDATE_PARAMS)
  .build();
final ByQueryResponse response = esRestTemplate.updateByQuery(
  updateQuery, IndexCoordinates.of(INDEX_ALIAS)
);
```

Now on _delete_by_query EVERYTHING is different (!!)

There is no UpdateQuery object
There is no updateByQuery method on ElasticsearchRestTemplate

Is there any reason for this?
What would be the right way to execute a _delete_by_query operation?
Is that I am doing something wrong or unexpected?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the same what I wrote in the [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2544):

> There is no UpdateQuery object

Why should there be an  `UpdateQuery` object in a delete request? In order to delete by query, we just need a query and the index to use, `ElasticsearchOperations` has these methods:

```
ByQueryResponse delete(Query query, IndexCoordinates index);
ByQueryResponse delete(Query query, Class<?> clazz, IndexCoordinates index);
```

The second method is needed to do proper field name mapping when `CriteriaQuery` is used.

For an update, much more information is needed than just the query, Therefore there is an `UpdateQuery` object that contains the `Query` and this additional information.

> There is no updateByQuery method on ElasticsearchRestTemplate

```
ByQueryResponse updateByQuery(UpdateQuery updateQuery, IndexCoordinates index);
```

was introduced in April 2021 with Spring Data Elasticsearch version 4.2 (which itself is out of support for one year now).